# sceditor add custom bbcode not working

Tags: javascript

can anyone explain me, why

```
$.sceditor.plugins.bbcode.bbcode.set("h1", {
    format: "[h1]{0}[/h1]",
    html: "<h1>{0}</h1>"
});
```

is not working? When I try to test it using [h1]test[/h1] it just returns

## 0

. I'm using sceditor in the current version.

Comment: Try this one`$.sceditor.plugins.bbcode.bbcode
    .set("h1", { tags: { h1: null }, format: "[h1]{0}[/h1]", html: "<h1>{0}</h1>" })`

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, however it didn't work. Using [h1]test[/h1] still returns <h1>0</h1>...